# Aligning popup widget in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've seen a number of replies on SO regarding this matter but not specifically to QMenu and QToolButton. Would appreciate some pointers on aligning the popup widget to the right side of the button. Here's a basic code I'm working off..

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 100)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        label = QLabel('Testing QToolButton Popup')
        toolbutton = QToolButton()
        toolbutton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        widget = QWidget()
        widgetLayout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        widgetLabel = QLabel('Popup Text')
        widgetSpinbox = QSpinBox()
        widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetLabel)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetSpinbox)

        widgetAction = QWidgetAction(toolbutton)
        widgetAction.setDefaultWidget(widget)

        widgetMenu = QMenu(toolbutton)
        widgetMenu.addAction(widgetAction)
        toolbutton.setMenu(widgetMenu)

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(toolbutton)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = test()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image: popup image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt developer thought the default position was correct, so if you want to modify the alignment you must move the QMenu as I show below:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QMenu,
    QSpinBox,
    QToolButton,
    QWidgetAction,
    QWidget,
)


class Menu(QMenu):
    def showEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            button = self.parentWidget()
            if button is not None:
                pos = button.mapToGlobal(button.rect().bottomRight())
                self.move(pos - self.rect().topRight())
        super().showEvent(event)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 100)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        label = QLabel("Testing QToolButton Popup")
        toolbutton = QToolButton(popupMode=QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        widgetLabel = QLabel("Popup Text")
        widgetSpinbox = QSpinBox()

        widget = QWidget()
        widgetLayout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetLabel)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetSpinbox)

        widgetAction = QWidgetAction(toolbutton)
        widgetAction.setDefaultWidget(widget)

        widgetMenu = Menu(toolbutton)
        widgetMenu.addAction(widgetAction)
        toolbutton.setMenu(widgetMenu)

        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(toolbutton)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want! I do have a question though, what does 'super().showEvent(event)' do?

Comment: @SureshKumar showEvent method is called by Qt when the widget is displayed. You must read the docs of Qt.

Comment: I have been going thru the documentation but clearly not grasping stuff lol. The reason I asked about the super() statement on the code is cause the solution you provided works with or without that line so was just wondering but thank you nonetheless for the pointers you provided.